# How can I read the value of my VS2010 configuration settings with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following settings:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="DstDataConnectionString" value="def" />
  <Setting name="SrcDataConnectionString" value="abc" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Can someone give me advice as to how I can read these settings from my C# program? I've no experience of getting this data so don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is add the system reference to the project code file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then you can pull those settings from the config file across into your c#.

For example, to call my connection string for you database and store it as a string variable:

```
string sqlconnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DstDataConnectionString"].ToString()
```

In this case you the sqlconnection string would store "def".

Answer (score 1):

I generally use appsettings or connectionstrings:

**Webconfig:**

```
<appSettings>   
   <add key="MySetting" value="MyValue"/> 
</appSettings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="......" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Code:**

```
using System.Configuration;

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"].ToString();
```

or

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;
```